# next button to grab next line of text in a text file

Tags: vb.net, forms, file

I've still be trying to learn how to make a quiz in vb.net.  I'm getting closer.  I have a button that reads next and one that reads submit.  I have a label that reads: Question 1:  and a text box that has the question in it.  I have a text box underneath the 1st text box that will have multiple choice answers.  How do I get the next button to read the next question in my text file so the person can choose an answer before moving to next question when hitting the next button?

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Button40_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button40.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Quiz\GenesisQuiz.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        TextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd & vbCrLf
        objReader.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong answer, please try again!")
    End If
End Sub
```

This of course reads the first question into the text box next to label Question 1:  If I put any more lines of text into the text file then all the lines get read into the textbox.
Thank you for your help.  I think it has to do with a For statement like:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To lineNumber - 1
```

Learning is fun!

Is this on the right track?

```
    Public Class Quiz
    Public question As String
    Public choices As String
    Public answer As String
    Public Score As Integer
    Public Sub New(question As String, choices As String, answer As String, score As Integer)
        Me.question = question
        Me.choices = Choices
        Me.answer = Answer
        Me.Score = Score
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub Button40_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button40.Click
    Dim QuizList As New List(Of Quiz)()
End Sub
End Class
```

Continuing to learn!  Thanks for your responses!

Comment: read the while file into a List(Of String) (or an array, if you must) and use them from there, no need to read the whole file each time.  Your `IF` statement is wonky too - the else to FileExists is FIleNotFound not "wrong Answer"

Comment: Thank you Plutonix for your constructive criticism!  I am trying to make a quiz - multiple choice quiz for a bible study app.  I have tried various ways of achieving that but haven't really liked what I was coming up with. I just want to add 1 question at a time so that a person has the opportunity to pick an answer before hitting the next button for the next question to pop up in the text box.  I am looking into the List(Of String) answer you gave me.  Thanks!

Comment: if it is multiple choice you ought to use a class to keep the Question, Choices and actual answer together. put them in a `List(of Quiz)`, show `QuizList(ndx)` then when they hit next, score it and increment `ndx` for the next one.

Comment: Another thing: text boxes are for text that can be edited.  Your question text is static, so use a label for it.  For multiple choice answers, use RadioButton controls if there is only one answer.  Use CheckBox controls in a "select all that apply" scenario.  (If you're not ready to learn these quite yet, you can have the user enter a number into a text box instead to get started, listing all the possible answers as part of the question text.  This will simplify Plutonix's advice too; you'll only need the question and the answer in your class.)

Comment: p. s. Plutonix is exactly right, however.  You ought to set it up the way he advises.  My simplification is to help you learn, not to improve on his advice.

Comment: p. p. s. You absolutely need to learn how to use the List object.  List is an object that contains a collection of other objects of like type.  Those objects can be some sort of existing class (such as String), or some class that you make (such as Quiz, which has all of the components of a single quiz question--the question, the possible answers, and the correct answer).  The List object's operations (methods) allow you to look up individual items in the List and display them.  That's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Plutonix and BobRodes for helping me out!

```
Public Class Form1
Dim lines() As String
Dim answers() As String
Dim index As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Quiz\GenesisQuiz.txt")
    answers = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Quiz\GenesisAnswers.txt")

Private Sub Button40_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button40.Click
    TextBox1.Text &= lines(index) & Environment.NewLine
    index += 1
    If index > lines.GetUpperBound(0) Then Button40.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button41_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button41.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button40_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button40.MouseClick
    If File.Exists("C:\Quiz\GenesisAnswers.txt") Then
        Dim ioFile As New StreamReader("C:\Quiz\GenesisAnswers.txt")
        TextBox2.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox3.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox4.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox5.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button41_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button41.MouseClick
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
End Sub
```

so this is what I have so far for my quiz.  Still a ways off but getting there.  Still learning and having fun.  Feel free to give constructive criticism!!!